# .gitignore add .env.development Didn't work?

Tags: git

> .gitignore

```
.env.production
.env.development
```

[image]

[image]

I try to run

```sh
git rm --cached .env.production
```

and I try to Restart the IDE, 
and I try to and commit

but  didn't work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to commit, but you would need to add first.

Check that with a `git status`: you should not see `.env.production` anymore, since it is ignored.

```
git check-ignore -v -- .env.production
```

Note: the `.gitignore` should be in the same folder or in a parent folder of the ignored files

Comment: I know.  I need to delete them first